# JaxB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Request xmlns="http://www.dccinterface.co.uk/ServiceUserGateway">
    <Header>
        <RequestID>124</RequestID>
        <CommandVariant>1</CommandVariant>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <ReadInventory>
            <DeviceID>11-22-22-33-55-66-77-88</DeviceID>
        </ReadInventory>
    </Body>
    <ns2:Signature xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ns2:SignedInfo Id="123"/>
    </ns2:Signature>
</Request>
```

But instead of above I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns="http://www.dccinterface.co.uk/ServiceUserGateway">
    <Header>
        <RequestID>124</RequestID>
        <CommandVariant>1</CommandVariant>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <ReadInventory>
            <DeviceID>11-22-22-33-55-66-77-88</DeviceID>
        </ReadInventory>
    </Body>
    <ns2:Signature>
        <ns2:SignedInfo Id="123"/>
    </ns2:Signature>
</Request>
```

NOTE : I have achieved  this using Xpath and DOM Processor.

Can you please suggest me is it any other way to do this other then DOM and XPath?

Below was the same code to remove the namespace uri from root and the uri to child tab.

To add the namespace to child element:

```
package com.dcc.serviceUserGateway;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import com.dcc.serviceUserGateway.Request.Body;
import com.dcc.serviceUserGateway.Request.Header;

public class SignatureTest {
    static JAXBContext jaxbContext1 = null;
    static JAXBContext jaxbContext2 = null;
    static {
        try {
            jaxbContext1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        Request request = new Request();
        Header header = new Header();
        header.setRequestID("124");
        header.setCommandVariant(BigInteger.valueOf(1l));
        Body body = new Body();
        ReadInventory inventory = new ReadInventory();
        inventory.setDeviceID("11-22-22-33-55-66-77-88");
        body.setReadInventory(inventory);
        SignatureType sig = new SignatureType();
        SignedInfoType type = new SignedInfoType();
        type.setId("123");
        sig.setSignedInfo(type);

        request.setHeader(header);
        request.setBody(body);
        request.setSignature(sig);

        String inputXML = asXmlString(request);
        System.out.println(inputXML);

        String xmlData = XPathUtils.removeNameSpace(inputXML);
        System.out
                .println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("xmlData = " + xmlData);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData
                .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        NodeList signatureNodes = document
                .getElementsByTagName("ns2:Signature");

        for (int i = 0; i < signatureNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) signatureNodes.item(i);
            item.setAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        }

        String output = transformDocumentToXmlString(document);
        System.out.println(output);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db1 = dbf1.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document1 = db1.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(output
                .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        NodeList signatureNodes1 = document1.getElementsByTagName("Request");
        for (int i = 0; i < signatureNodes1.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) signatureNodes1.item(i);
            item.setAttribute("xmlns",
                    "http://www.dccinterface.co.uk/ServiceUserGateway");
        }

        String requestXML = transformDocumentToXmlString(document1);
        System.out.println(requestXML);

    }

    private static String transformDocumentToXmlString(Document document)
            throws TransformerException {
        try {
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            Result result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String asXmlString(Object bean) throws TransformerException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try {
            if (jaxbContext1 != null) {
                Marshaller m = jaxbContext1.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                m.marshal(bean, new StreamResult(sw));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TransformerException(
                    "Couldn't be generated XML string from bean object.", e);
        }
        return sw.toString();

    }
}
```

To remove namespace in root:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "false");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputSource);
Node root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList rootchildren = root.getChildNodes();
Element newroot = xmlDoc.createElement(root.getNodeName());
for (int i = 0; i < rootchildren.getLength(); i++) {
    newroot.appendChild(rootchildren.item(i).cloneNode(true));
}
xmlDoc.replaceChild(newroot, root);
DOMSource requestXMLSource = new DOMSource(xmlDoc.getDocumentElement());
StringWriter requestXMLStringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult requestXMLStreamResult = new StreamResult(requestXMLStringWriter);
transformer.transform(requestXMLSource, requestXMLStreamResult);
String modifiedRequestXML = requestXMLStringWriter.toString();
return modifiedRequestXML;
```

Kindly provide me the best solution other then this.

Comment: to the above sample output  , i have 2 XSD's Base XSD contains Request and Body , Imported XSD contains signature

Comment: Instead of pasting code, please describe the problem you are encountering and your approach to solve it. This is not a _we will fix your code_ community, but if you show some effort by yourself, there will hopefully be people who will happily help you.

Answer (score 0):

the name space definition with prefix must be done in the root element. What you want is not allowed in XML.

Comment: That statement is incorrect. See [Namespaces is XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping-defaulting): "*The scope of a namespace declaration declaring a prefix extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag*"

Comment: @Meyer but this is only true if no prefix is used.

Comment: No, that includes prefixed declarations. This is common in [SOAP messages](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#firstexample) for example.